# #!/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

The shebang line in my `bin/www` file is:

```
pi:~/ferc$ head -n 1 bin/www
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

However, executing it:

```
pi:~/ferc$ bin/www
bin/www: line 1: #!/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory
```

The `env` file does exist:

```
pi:~/ferc$ ls -lL /usr/bin/env
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 31408 Feb 18  2016 /usr/bin/env
```

The `node` file also exists:

```
pi:~/ferc$ ls -al /usr/bin/node
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul  7 18:29 /usr/bin/node -> /usr/bin/nodejs
```

And `node` runs fine:

```
pi:~/ferc$ node -v
v4.2.6
```

What does the error message really mean? Which file is it complaining about?

Comment: what `which node` says?

Comment: The error message implies that it's trying to execute a file named "#!/usr/bin/env" and failing. I think the first line of `bin/www` is corrupt in some way, and it's not being recognized as a shebang.

Comment: @Kenster, thanks for the tip. I ran the file through `dos2unix` and the error goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause was a corrupted file, probably due to a mixture of LF and CF/LF line endings in the file.

What happened were:

1. I copied the file from a Windows PC to the AWS ec2 Ubuntu instance.
2. First time I ran the www file, that same error message appeared. The cause at this point was probably the `node` executable did not exist. I hadn't created the symbolic link yet.
3. While trying to troubleshoot, I edited and saved the www file using nano. I think at this point the file got corrupted.
4. Later, I added the symbolic link for /usr/bin/node. However, the same error persisted, but probably due to the corrupted line endings.
5. I `dos2unix` the www file, and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node directly like:

```
#!/usr/bin/node
```

See pros and cons: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my